# Using mongoose in multiple routes with express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, export, router

I have set up my code in server.js which worked fine. I am now trying to clean up the server.js code by splitting the code into different routes.

I am using the express.Router to link up the files but i am struggling to understand why my post route is braking.

In the server.js file

```
// dependencies
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// routes
constpurchaseOrders = require("./routes/purchaseOrders");
app.use("/purchaseOrders", purchaseOrders);

// listen
app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

In the purchaseOrders.js file

```
// dependencies
const express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("Mongoose");
const connection = require("../routes/mongoose.js");
const Po = require("../routes/schemas.js:);

// post route
router.post("/addpo, function(req.res){
//long code lines here  
po.save();
res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

So with this route, i have the following end point on the route.get:

```
10.0.0.15:3000/purchaseOrders/addpo
```

Now the problem comes in when i submit the form, it returns "cannot POST /addpo" and the end point shows:

```
10.0.0.15:3000/addpo
```

On my ejs file i have set the form up as follows:

```
<form action="/addpo" method="post">
```

On the mongoose.js connection i export as follows:

```
module.exports = mongoose;
```

On the schemas.js i export:

```
module.exports = Po;
```

I know I did something wrong with the routing but i cannot figure our why.

Thanks alot :-)

Comment: I guess this bug is only in the question, but the quotation marks are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need the `/addpo` path to work, change this on `server.js`:

```
app.use("/", purchaseOrders);
```

**NOT**

```
app.use("/purchaseOrders", purchaseOrders);
```

---

**Other option**

server.js:

```
app.use("/addpo", purchaseOrders);
```

purchaseOrders.js

```
router.post("/", function(req.res){
```

If you add a route before calling a router it will be added in front of it.

So, yo can use the route `action="/addpo"` in the html.

[Express docs](https://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html#express-router)

Comment: Well that did it like magic. Thank you Jorge. The only thing i dont understand is Im expecting 10.0.0.15:3000/purchaseOrders/addpo. But now the post works because its seing the 10.0.0.15:3000/addpo end point. Do you know if there is a way for the post to work on the full /purchaseOrders/addpo. instead of just /addpo?

Comment: @Jax yes, just change the action: action="/purchaseOrders/addpo" and keep the code as you had it. If you found the answer helpful, I would appreciate it if you would accept it. Best regards.

Comment: Thank you @Jorge Montejo. The good thing is you helped me getting the code to work like it was before the routing. What is breaking my brain is the action="/purchaseOrders/addpo" was the first thing that i tried that made sense to me but its still giving me the "cannot POST /addpo" with the 10.0.0.15:3000/addpo.